# Identify Lego set containing a trailer with light-blue & purple color theme

Tags: set-identification, friends

This looks like some kind of trailer with light-blue & purple color theme.

[image]

From what set is this come from?

Answer (score 5):

Yup, good guess.

Comes form [*Set# 41026 Sunshine Harvest*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41026-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image]